# AJAX to MySQL WHERE IN ($_GET) request. Exclude certain results

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, checkbox, where-in

When I click on "Asus" checkbox the result is all models of "Asus" with all 'sizes', good. But when I click on "Asus" AND "15''" checkboxes both, the result is all models of this size including "Acer" and so on. How it must work( at least in my imagination:)) - click both on "Asus" and "15''" and get data relating only to clicked (checked) checkboxes.

Thank you.

Checkboxes:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="Acer"> Acer
    <input type="checkbox" name="Asus"> Asus
...
    <input type="checkbox" name="15.6"> 15''
    <input type="checkbox" name="17"> 17''
```

JQuery/Ajax:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    var ids = [];
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    ids.push($(this).attr("name"));
    });
    ids = ids.join(",");

    $.get("mysql.php", {q: ids}, 
    function(result) {
    $("div#output").html(result);

    }); 
});
```

MySQL query:

```
$g = $_GET['q'];
if(isset($g))   {
    $param = "" . str_replace(",", "','", $_GET['q']) . "";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `notebook` WHERE `trademark` IN ('$param') OR `size` IN ('$param') ORDER BY `trademark`";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<p>'.$row['trademark'].' = '.$row['size'].'</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Before running your `$_GET` variables straight into an SQL query, you might take a gander at http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 params to filter results, you must work with them separately.

my suggest:

checkboxes:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="trademark" value="Acer"> Acer
    <input type="checkbox" name="trademark" value="Asus"> Asus
....    
    <input type="checkbox" name="size" value="15.6"> 15''
    <input type="checkbox" name="size" value="17"> 17''
```

jquery:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    var trade = [];
    var sizes= [];
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
       if($(this).attr("name")=="trademark"){
            trade.push($(this).val());
       }
       else{
            sizes.push($(this).val());
       }
    });
    trade = trade.join(",");
    sizes= sizes.join(",");
    $.get("mysql.php", {q: trade,p: sizes}, 
    function(result) {
    $("div#output").html(result);
    }); 
});
```

the mysql:

```
$g = $_GET['q'];
$h = $_GET['p'];
$wheresql="";
$where=0;
if(isset($g))   {
    $where=1;
    $param = "" . str_replace(",", "','", $_GET['q']) . "";
    $wheresql.="`trademark` IN ('$param')";
}
if(isset($h))   {
    if($where==1){$wheresql.=" AND ";}
    $where=1;
    $param = "" . str_replace(",", "','", $_GET['p']) . "";
    $wheresql.="`size` IN ('$param')";
}
if($where==1){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `notebook` WHERE ".$wheresql." ORDER BY `trademark`";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<p>'.$row['trademark'].' = '.$row['size'].'</p>';
    }

}
```

little explanation: you have 2 groups of checkboxes distinguished by its name, and working with them separately in the jquery code, making possible send them to the mysql search in 2 variables, then in the mysql search script, for each variable do its "where" to do the search, the `$where` variable have 2 purposes: first add the `" AND "` to the sql if there are any trademark and size checked, second: check if there are any criteria to search (if there are called with no params, it wont do the search).

I have not tested the code :P

Sorry for my English

Comment: Pablo thanks a lot. Your code is perfect. I've just fix mysql syntax for my localhost MySQL version. Gracias. Creo que la pregunta está cerrada) sorry for my Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want to use AND instead of OR?

If you're getting results for all the matching trademarks and all the matching sizes, then you should use AND, which only returns results when it matches the trademark AND the size.

Comment: Using AND do not solve the problem. When you click on first parameter "Asus" it will wait for second parameter "size". But i want to get data after each clicking.

Comment: Two options. Either use JavaScript to filter the current set of results to only the select size, or resent the trademark and size and get a new list of models, then clear the current list and rebuild it with the new list.